# Setting permanent MAC address in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, mac

Due to the unusual way my ISP set up Internet, I need to manually set up MAC address to go online.
So far I've been using:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

However, I have to enter this command every time I start my computer.
How to set MAC address permanently?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an **udev** rule to automatically set the *MAC* address on your network interface

Create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-custom-mac.rules` and paste into it:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", RUN+="/sbin/ip link set dev %k address YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY"
```

where `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` is the original MAC address of your interface (you can get it in the output of `ip link`) and `YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY` is the new MAC address you want to enforce.

To make the change effective you can run

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

but I doubt it works, so a **reboot** might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a shell script with this commands:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Save the file with .sh extension and make it startup program ("Add Script" and select your script file)

Tell me how it was ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I created a .sh file with these scripts in my documents and added it as a startup program in Startup Applications Manager. Didn't help, still had to enter the commands manually in terminal.

Answer (score -3):

Copy all the matter in the terminal

---

sudo ifconfig eth0 down && sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:4a:82:d5:e4:c6 && sudo ifconfig eth0 up

Comment: how does this make it permanent?